# Perform segue when cell with ID is selected

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to create a segue happen when a cell has been selected. I have tired using `cell.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("")`. However it is returning "nil" whilst unwrapping. I have set up the cells ID correctly and they match. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
if menuTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("") == "logout" {
            print("logout")
            performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps this is a stupid question, but in your code you're replacing the empty string for id with the real id, right? Are you using a static table? Also why are you comparing to a string? menuTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("") returns a cell so that comparison will fail. Also why not just implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and compare the indexPath.row?

Comment: the 'deSelect' was a miss type that has now been fixed. My IF statement now looks like - if index.row == int { }. Would you say that this is a correct and reliable way of segueing from a static cells. Sorry I'm new to swift

Comment: Yes, it should work. If you're using static cells you can also make iboutlets and ibactions directly to the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a UITableView delegate method for when a user selects a cell, this is good for knowing when a user has selected a cell, but we need to identify if it is the logout cell that has been pressed.

To identify the cell we'll be setting the tag property of the your logout cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //this is the indexPath row where we want our login cell to be showed
        let loginCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("login", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoginTableViewCell
        //set the tag so when we select the cell we can see if the cell we have selected has a tag of 5
        loginCell.tag = 5
        return loginCell
    }else {
        //here goes our other cells, in this case they'll just be normal UITableViewCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

In our `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method we'll instantiate the loginTableViewCell in the first row and set its tag to 5, if the row isn't 0 we simply return our normal cell

So now we have a cell where the tag is 5 and all the other cells do not have a default tag property of 0, now, when the user selects a cell we can check for this method in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of our table view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    if cell.tag == 5 {
        //cell is login cell
        //perform segue here            
    }
}
```

This delegate method gives us the table view and the indexPath of the selected cell. Now we call `CellForRowAtIndexPath` on the table view to get the cell that was selected. Now that we have the cell we can compare the cell's tag. If the tag is 5 the logout cell was selected so we can perform our segue there.